# Django: Css não importado

Tags: python-3.x, django, aplicação-web, django-templates

Estou desenvolvendo meu primeiro site com o Django e me deparei com um problema: Ao executar a **aplicação no browser**, as **alterações contidas no arquivo css não se aplicam ao site** quando tento importar o css com o comando <link rel="stylesheet" href={% static'css/cabecalho.css/' %}/>.

Nessa etapa do projeto o site está assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Meu arquivo HTML se chama cabecalho.html (templates/django/cabecalho.html) e é o seguinte:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load static %} <!-- Nova linha que carrega os arquivos estáticos -->
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Django Form Exemplo</title>
         <link rel="stylesheet" href={% static'css/cabecalho.css' %}/>
    </head>

    <body>
     <div class='logo'>
     <img src="{% static "images/logo.png" %}" alt="Logo da Hacked" />
     </div>

     <div class='menu'>
       <a href="/app/sobre/">Sobre</a>
       <a href="/app/sair/">Sair</a>
     </div>

     <div class='bemvindo'>
       <h2>Bem vindo ao nosso Site Django Exemplo!</h2>
     </div>

    </body>

   </html>
```

Esse arquivo contém a "**{% load static %}**" e importo o css na linha:

**<link rel="stylesheet" href={% static'css/cabecalho.css' %}/>**

Entretanto o site continua com a configuração da figura acima e as alterações contidas no css não são "aplicadas".

Por outro lado, ao substituir essa linha pelo código contido no arquivo css as as mudanças desejadas ocorrem normalmente:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

{% load static %} <!-- Nova linha que carrega os arquivos estáticos -->

<html>

  <head>
    <title>Django Form Exemplo</title>
           <style>
           body {
            font-family: Segoe UI;
           }
           .logo {
            float: left;
           }
           .logo img {
            width: 250px;
            padding: 20px;
           }
           .menu {
            float: right;
            padding: 40px;
            font-size: 15pt;
           }
           .menu a {
            margin-left: 15px;
            margin-right: 15px;
           }
           .bemvindo {
            clear: both;
            padding: 0 20px;
           }

           </style>
</head>

<body>
 <div class='logo'>
   <img src="{% static "images/logo.png" %}" alt="Logo da Hacked" />
 </div>

 <div class='menu'>
   <a href="/app/sobre/">Sobre</a>
   <a href="/app/sair/">Sair</a>
 </div>

 <div class='bemvindo'>
   <h2>Bem vindo ao nosso Site Django Exemplo!</h2>
 </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Mudanças desejadas:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Meu arquivo css se chama cabecalho.css (static/css/cabecalho.css) e é o seguinte:

```
  <style>
           body {
            font-family: Segoe UI;
           }
           .logo {
            float: left;
           }
           .logo img {
            width: 250px;
            padding: 20px;
           }
           .menu {
            float: right;
            padding: 40px;
            font-size: 15pt;
           }
           .menu a {
            margin-left: 15px;
            margin-right: 15px;
           }
           .bemvindo {
            clear: both;
            padding: 0 20px;
           }

           </style>
```

Demais informações:

views.py (app/views.py):

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse


def index(request):


    
    return render(request, 'django/cabecalho.html')
```

settings.py (project/settings.py):

```
 # Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
 # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/

 STATIC_PATH = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')  # concatena a pasta static a variavel instanciada 
 base_dir que aponta para a raiz do projeto

 STATIC_URL = '/static/' # chamada que terá no browswer para a pasta de arquivos estaticos

 STATICFILES_DIRS = (
            STATIC_PATH,
 )
```

Pastas:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Você não deu o espaço a frente do static `<link rel="stylesheet" href={% static'css/cabecalho.css' %}/>`

Comment: Iago, testei com o espaço mas não teve nenhuma alteração.

Answer (score -1):

Verifica mudar *STATIC_PATH = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')* para *STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')* e exclui o *STATICFILES_DIRS = (STATIC_PATH,)*

Verifica também se a pasta static/css que contém o arquivo *cabecalho.css* está dentro da mesma pasta do app.

Caso não funcione, tenta copiar o cabecalho.css pra pasta seu_projeto/lib/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/css/

Coloque aspas duplas entre os colchetes:
*href=**"**{% static 'css/cabecalho.css/' %}**"**/>*

Comment: Carlos a alteração proposta na verdade fez com que o logo (Hacked) não fosse carregado.

Comment: tem um detalhe que só vi agora _<link rel="stylesheet" href={% static'css/cabecalho.css' %}/>_ está faltando aspas duplas " " entre os colchetes <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static'css/cabecalho.css' %}"/>

Eu não sei onde li que essa pergunta era de 4 anos atrás... tô ficando maluco

Comment: Acontece kkk Fiz um teste com as aspas duplas e adicionando um espaço depois de static mas continua sem aplicar as mudanças.